# What Is The Correct Syntax For MFA For An Elixir Module?

Tags: elixir

I'm playing with trying to call :erlang.trace_pattern/2.  As I often do with such things I thought I'd start with something simple and then add more complexity as I got better acquainted.  However in this case I can't seem to get the simple part right.

I'm trying to pass Elixir's String.contains?/2 to :erlang.trace_pattern/2.  I've tried this call:

```
:erlang.trace_pattern({:"Elixir.String","contains?",2},[])
```

Which returns:

```
** (ArgumentError) errors were found at the given arguments:

  * 1st argument: invalid MFA specification

    :erlang.trace_pattern({String, "contains?", 2}, [])
```

One thing that struck me as odd was the fact that the Elixir preface on the module name dropped off.  I've also tried this:

```
:erlang.trace_pattern({:string, 'contains?', 2}, [])
```

Which returns:

```
** (ArgumentError) errors were found at the given arguments:

  * 1st argument: invalid MFA specification

    :erlang.trace_pattern({String, 'contains?', 2}, [])
```

I've tried a few combinations and I can't seem to figure out what I need to do to make this work.  The Erlang docs say the type of the first argument is `{Module, Function, Arity}` and I'm confident I've got at least the arity part right but the other two seem to be eluding me. What is the right syntax for this call?

If it makes any difference I'm trying this in 1.14.0 on MacOS in iex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2nd argument must be an atom:

```
:erlang.trace_pattern({String, :contains?, 2}, true)
```

You'll see this if you ever use the `apply/3` function, e.g.

```
iex> apply(String, :upcase, ["hello"])
"HELLO"
```

Also, be careful with single-quotes in Elixir: they are a shorthand for "character lists", which means that `'thing'` and `"thing"` represent different things.

FYI: the Elixir module names, e.g. `String` are prefixed automagically somewhere with `Elixir.`, so `String == :"Elixir.String"`

Comment: Looking at it now I can see that the MFA spec does clearly say `atom()` for the second parameter.  I'm not sure how I missed that.